# Concatenating a session variable in query syntax

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to replace the database/schema definition directly in a query. Ideally, something like this (ignore the actual query, it's just fluff):

```
SET A_DBS = 'A_DATABASE.A_SCHEMA';
SET B_DBS = 'B_DATABASE.B_SCHEMA';
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO IDENTIFIER($B_DBS)."TABLE" SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER($A_DBS)."TABLE";
```

The only way I've found to do this is also define a variable for each table. Such as:

```
SET A_TABLE = CONCAT($A_DBS, ',', 'TABLE');
SET B_TABLE = CONCAT($B_DBS, ',', 'TABLE');

INSERT OVERWRITE INTO IDENTIFIER($B_TABLE) SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER($A_TABLE);
```

But I'd rather not do that, especially for queries with many tables. So...is what I'm looking for possible?

Comment: The table-literals doc's imply is need to be your latter example: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/literals-table.html